# password for jenkins: jenkins is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported

Tags: ssh, sudo, password, jenkins

I have added jenkins as a sudo user in my build node:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG sudo jenkins
```

This also works on the build node. However, in my build log there is:

```
[sudo] password for jenkins: jenkins is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

What could cause this?

I was trying run `echo ${PASSWORD} | sudo -S make install` on the build node.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are not "jenkins"?  To add a user to the 'sudo' group, you need to be in the sudo group already.  If you are running as user "jenkins" and "jenkins" does not have sudo privileges, then a user with those privileges needs to add "jenkins" to the group.

Comment: Yes, I'm not jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was simple: reboot.

Comment: I was just going to suggest that!